# How to add watermark to remote image before download?

Tags: php, image, watermark

So i've got a an image gallery website of sorts where the images are uploaded on gdrive or other cloud services. There is a direct download button which downloads the image from that source. I was wondering if there is a way to add a watermark to the image before download using php when the user clicks the download button. I found this link on stackoverflow which says that it's possible but does not share any details on how:  [Automatically adding watermark on image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377389/automatically-adding-watermark-on-image-download).
I found a few ways online which show how to add watermarks to locally stored images but i could not find a way to add it to a remote image. Any help is appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The basic idea would be to create a temporary HTML Canvas and draw the image with an overlay before downloading it. https://codepen.io/ahebler/pen/KzyQBZ should give you some ideas.